# How to change parameters in executable .jar file on command line?

Tags: java, jar, terminal

I am not a very experienced coder, but I had a question about changing the arguments in a certain .jar file I am trying to execute in Terminal. The documentation for the command line app is available here:

https://bd2kccd.github.io/docs/causal-cmd/

The usage described for the algorithm I am trying to run is given as this under FGESd:

usage: java -jar causal-cmd-x.x.x-SNAPSHOT.jar --algorithm FGESd [-d ] [--exclude-variables ] -f  [--faithfulness-assumed] [--help] [--json] [--knowledge ] [--max-degree ] [--no-validation-output] [-o ] [--output-prefix ] [--sample-prior ] [--skip-category-limit] [--skip-latest] [--skip-unique-var-name] [--structure-prior ] [--symmetric-first-step] [--tetrad-graph-json] [--thread ] [--verbose]

I am trying to change the parameters --structure-prior and --sample-prior, but the obvious solution of just replacing the value in the tags does not work. How do I write a line with these changed parameters? The other elements of the line aren't necessary since they will remain default. I have tried also keeping the values in the tags. The output shows the value for all inputed parameters, and the values don't change despite me changing them on the command line.

The download for the .jar file is available here:

https://cloud.ccd.pitt.edu/nexus/content/repositories/releases/edu/cmu/causal-cmd/

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "change parameters"? Do you want to run the jar and have trouble with how to pass parameters? Or are you trying something else like modifying the jar itself and how it handles parameters, for some reason/purpose? Really unclear. If you have trouble running the jar (btw that would not be a programming question), please show exactly what you tried, what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: I actually managed to resolve the issue. Thanks